# Remote API with WIFI enabled Camcorders

Tags: camera, sony

I currently own a CX330, which has WIFI control through a Sony app.  I would like to build the remote control features into another app I'm building as well as being able to download video from the device.  Are either of these options possible and, if so, where in the documentation do I go to find examples or instructions?  Currently I only see these functions available for a limited set of devices, but if the proprietary software can provide remote control I'm assuming Sony has not built a separate API just for the camcorders and a different one for other devices.

Also, I believe the proprietary software allows you to download new videos directly from the camera, is an api available for this as well?

Comment: Out of scope for SO, but you could use ethereal to snoop the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do have an API for working with cameras, but unfortunately your camera is not supported. You can find the full list of supported cameras here:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

The API does allow you to download photos and videos.

Comment: I haven't actually used it, I'm going off the information that PlayMemories works with it to perform those functions.